# Change the object preview into one of its own attributes

Tags: python

How to change object printing preview into desirable name ?

```
class Person:
    def __init___(self):
       self.name = name 
       self.age = age

man1 = Person("Jhon",32)
print(man1)
>>> <__main__.Person object at 0x7f9780554b80>
```

I need to change the preview of object into specifice attribute .(e.g: obj.name , in this example i want the preview will be "Jhon_Person_obj" instead the adress of it)

This code describe the printing  reasult i need.

```
print(Jhon_Person_obj)
print(Jhon_Person_obj.age)
>>> <__main__.Personobject at 0x7f9780554bb0>
>>> 32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `__repr__` method of your class:

```
# PEP8: Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.
class Pokemon():

     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

     def __repr__(self):
         return f"Pokemon(name='{self.name}')"
```

Usage:

```
p = Pokemon('Pikachu')
print(p)

# Output
Pokemon(name='Pikachu')
```

Comment: Do u know what wrong with my question that i got -1?